# How does the Clr know where the il code for class/field definitions are?

Tags: c#, metadata, clr

I was recently reading Clr Via C# (great book btw) but I am a bit confused. In Clr metadata, the method rva defines where the code for a method is located in ram (yes, I know it's an offset). However using ildasm I don't see any of this for class definitions, field definitions, or anything not a method. How does the Clr know where all the other code is?

Comment: If you read the C# code of Mono Cecil (or other similar projects), you can see how it analyze raw bytes of the assembly files to locate such information. That's also how CLR does the same. Microsoft does open source .NET Core CLR, so you can read the actual code in CoreCLR (in C/C++).

Comment: Very interesting. I am assuming the CLR does not do this for methods because of the sheer size of the data and that's whey they have the RVA in metadata. Am I correct? (Sorry for taking a while, trip w/ family)